# WEB3.PHP Contract Call

Tags: php, ethereum, bsc, web3php

I am using this PHP library https://github.com/web3p/web3.php to make the requests to smart contracts on BSC.

```
$web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org');
$contract = new Contract($web3->provider, $abi);

$contract->at('0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E')->call('WETH', function($err, $result) {
    print_r($result);
});
```

Works perfectly but the problem is when I try to call a function that has parameters both uint256 and address[] . For example

[image]

And here's the code:

```
$contract->at('0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E')->call('quote', [
    '25000000000000000000',
    '[0x8C851d1a123Ff703BD1f9dabe631b69902Df5f97, 0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56]',
], function($err, $result) {
    print_r($result);
});
```

I get the following error. Tried to send the parameters as dictionary with param name. Couldn't figure out how should be done.

> InvalidArgumentException
> Please make sure you have put all function params and callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your snippet tries to encode the second param as an array but you're passing a string.
2. The number of `$params` is dynamic in the PHP code, don't wrap them in an array.

```
$contract->at('0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E')->call(
    // function name
    'getAmountsOut',

    // note the removed array wrapper

    // first param
    '25000000000000000000',

    // second param
    [
        '0x8C851d1a123Ff703BD1f9dabe631b69902Df5f97',
        '0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56'
    ],

    // callback
    function($err, $result) {
        print_r($result);
    }
);
```

Comment: Works but it return this:  Array ( [0] => phpseclib\Math\BigInteger Object ( [value] => 0x [engine] => gmp ) )

Comment: @Extrangeplanet Solidity `uint256` type may return a value that won't fit into PHP `int` type. So the authors of the web3php library decided to use the `BigInteger` instead of native `int`. You can return the number as a `String` using the `toString()` method (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php#L186C21-L186C29) or by directly typecasting it to a string: `(string)$result` .